# How to fire up a code when changes happens on another document?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

As in the question I'm trying to fire up a code when a event happens, in my case  I got the following index.html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {  
        console.log("changed key: " + event.key);
        console.log("old value  : " + event.newValue);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here I'm trying to put a item in the localStorage to trigger the javascript code from index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    window.localStorage.setItem("sss", "test");
    console.log(window.localStorage.getItem("sss"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Couldn't get the output working unfortunately, any ideas?

Comment: Works for me when I copy those, open the first one, then open the second afterward (in a separate tab, of course).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I only see "test", while I'm trying to get: "changed key: sss  old value: ...." for example

Comment: Just to be clear, what you need to do is: 1. Open the first file in a tab. 2. Open a new tab. 3. Open the second file in that tab *while the other tab is still open*. Then you should see the event occur. **Note:** If `sss` *already* has the value `"test"`, you won't get an event because it's not a change. So for testing, you might consider `localStorage.setItem("sss", Date.now());` or something like that so it's a different value (almost) every time.